# Jenkins timeout not aborting job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, try-catch, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline where I have the following code (jenkinsfile):

```
stage('My stage') {
  options {
    timeout(time: 5, unit: "MINUTES")
  }
  steps {
    script {
       ./run_script.sh
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this code I was expecting that If the run_script.sh would take more than 5 minutes, the job would abort.
But this is not the case (even with jenkins telling me "Sending interrupt signal to process").. After running the job I get this:

```
...
17:09:40  Timeout set to expire in 5 min 0 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
17:09:40  ./run_script.sh                   '                  
17:14:40  Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
17:14:40  Sending interrupt signal to process
17:14:48  ...
17:14:48  + JOB_NAME=...
17:14:48  + BUILD_URL=...
17:14:48  + BUILD_ID=777
17:14:48  + BUILD_RESULT=SUCCESS
```

The job gets executed and I can see the green success status in jenkins.
Why is this happening and how can I make it so when a timeout occurs the job gets aborted?

EDIT:
Not sure if this is relevant or not but the run_script.sh is a script which connects to a remote server using ssh and runs some docker commands (docker run...). Running this script using timeout gives me the following msgs:

```
...
12:07:22 Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
12:07:22 Sending interrupt signal to process........
.........
Finished: SUCCESS
```

[image]

As you can see the status stays success instead of aborted!!!
I need to capture this "timeout" so I can send notifications to users. One way would be to capture the aborted status but if the status is success how can i do it?

The run_script.sh looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

ssh user@server.com "
 ssh -p 30 xdy@localhost ' docker run --rm --name cont1 -e FTP_USER=$User -e FTP_PASSWD=$Pass -v /home/logs:/usr/myapp -w /usr/myapp server2.com:3000/mylog:1.1 python script.py' "
```

script.py is a simple script to copy some files from a server to another.

Answer (score 1):

The docker run command is swallowing the exception. Even though it sends the interrupt signal, the docker run returns a status code of 0. If you want to have the docker run command return exit code 143 instead, and subsequently throw the exception, you can use the docker run --init option.